# error message when installing drupal 8

Tags: debugging

When I was installing Drupal 8 (Macos, nginx, php7.0, mysql5.6), the following error occurred, Can someone help me?

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /core/install.php?langcode=zh- 
hans&profile=standard&continue=1&id=1&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
Warning:  Declaration of 
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder::callMethod($service, 
$call) should be compatible with Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder::callMethod($service, $call, SplObjectStorage $inlinedDefinitions) in /Users/xile/code/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 22
Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException: Configuration objects (block.block.bartik_help, block.block.bartik_search, 
block.block.seven_help, contact.form.feedback, 
core.entity_form_display.node.article.default, 
core.entity_form_display.node.page.default, 
core.entity_form_display.user.user.default, 
core.entity_view_display.node.article.default, 
core.entity_view_display.node.article.teaser, 
core.entity_view_display.user.user.compact, 
core.entity_view_display.user.user.default, 
field.field.node.article.field_image, 
field.field.user.user.user_picture, field.storage.node.field_image, 
field.storage.node.field_tags, field.storage.user.user_picture, 
rdf.mapping.comment.comment, rdf.mapping.node.article, 
rdf.mapping.node.page, rdf.mapping.taxonomy_term.tags, 
taxonomy.vocabulary.tags) provided by standard have unmet dependencies in Drupal\Core\Config\UnmetDependenciesException::create()(line 89 of /Users/xile/code/drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/UnmetDependenciesException.php).
```

Answer (score 1):

Install drupal console and then try to install the site using drupal console

https://drupalconsole.com/articles/how-to-install-drupal-console

```
drupal si
```